# My innerHTML is saying undefined , i want to get innerHTML to input

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on a vanilla javascript TODO list with variou functionality like editing , adding deleting todos.
But I am failing to edit it because i cannot fetch the required HTML to the input tag.
Here is the relatede HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Grocery Bud</title>
    <!-- font-awesome -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <!-- styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="section-center">
      <!-- form -->
      <form class="grocery-form">
        <p class="alert"></p>
        <h3>Grocery Bud</h3>
        <div class="form-control">
          <input type="text" id="grocery" placeholder="e.g. eggs">
          <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <!-- list -->
      <div class="grocery-container">
        <div class="grocery-list">
        </div>
        <!-- button -->
        <button type="button" class="clear-btn">clear items</button>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- javascript -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my javascript code.

```
// ****** SELECT ITEMS **********

const alert = document.querySelector('.alert');
const form = document.querySelector('.grocery-form');
const grocery = document.getElementById('grocery');
const submitBtn = document.querySelector('.submit-btn');
const container = document.querySelector('.grocery-container');
const list = document.querySelector('.grocery-list');
const clearBtn = document.querySelector('.clear-btn');


// edit option


let editElement;
let editFlag = false;
let editID = "";

// display alert
const displayAlert = (text,action)=>{
    alert.textContent = text;
    alert.classList.add(`alert-${action}`);

    // remove alert
    setTimeout(() => {
        alert.textContent = '';
        alert.classList.remove(`alert-${action}`);
    }, 1000);
}
// clear item

const clearItems = () => {
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('.grocery-item');

    if (items.length > 0) {
        items.forEach(item => {
            list.removeChild(item);
        })
    }
    container.classList.remove('show-container');
    displayAlert('Empty list', 'danger');
    setBackToDefault();
    // localStorage.removeItem('list');
}


// remove from local storage item
const removeFromLocalStorage = (id) => {
    
}

// delete function
const deleteItem = e => {
    // console.log("Item Deleted.");
    const element = e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
    const id = element.dataset.id; 
    list.removeChild(element);
    if (list.children.length === 0) {
        container.classList.remove('show-container');
    }
    displayAlert("Item removed", "danger");
    setBackToDefault();
    // remove from local storage
    // removeFromLocalStorage(id);
}
// edit function
const editItem = (e) => {
    // console.log("Item Edited.");
    const element = e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
    // set edit item
    editElement = e.currentTarget.parentElement.previousElementSiblings;
    // set from value
    grocery.value = editElement.innerHTML;
    editFlag = true;
}


// local storage
const addTolocalStorage = (id, value) => {
    console.log('added to local storage.');
}
// set back to default

const setBackToDefault = () => {
    // console.log('Setted back to default.');
    grocery.value = "";
    editFlag = false;
    editID = "";
    submitBtn.textContent = "submit";
}


// ****** FUNCTIONS **********
const addItem = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(grocery.value);
    const value = grocery.value.trim();
    const id = new Date().getTime().toString();
    
    if (value && !editFlag) {
        const element = document.createElement('article');
        // add class
        element.classList.add('grocery-item');
        // add id
        const attr = document.createAttribute('data-id');
        attr.value = id;
        element.setAttributeNode(attr);
        element.innerHTML = ` <p class="title">${value}</p>
            <div class="btn-container">
              <button type="button" class="edit-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="delete-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
              </button>
            </div>`;
        
        const deleteBtn = element.querySelector('.delete-btn');
        const editBtn = element.querySelector('.edit-btn');

        deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', deleteItem);
        editBtn.addEventListener('click', editItem);

        // append chiled
        list.appendChild(element);
        // display alert
        displayAlert('item added to the list.', 'success');
        // show container
        container.classList.add('show-container');
        // add to localstorage
        addTolocalStorage(id, value);
        // set back to default 
        setBackToDefault();
    }
    else if (!value && editFlag) {
        console.log("Editing...");
    }
    else {
        displayAlert('PLease enter velue...', 'danger');
    }
    
}



// ****** EVENT LISTENERS **********
// submit form
form.addEventListener('submit', addItem);

// clear items
clearBtn.addEventListener('click', clearItems);
```

The arrow function named editItem has a line with innerHTML. Here i have to get the innerHTML in the input  in order to edit it.
Please help meout someone.

```
// edit function
const editItem = (e) => {
    // console.log("Item Edited.");
    const element = e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
    // set edit item
    editElement = e.currentTarget.parentElement.previousElementSiblings;
    // set from value
    grocery.value = editElement.innerHTML;
    editFlag = true;
}
```

Comment: "I cannot fetch the required HTML to the input tag". What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the value of an input try with this:

```
grocery.value = editElement.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the editElement to element.firstElementChild and youre good

```
   const editItem = (e) => {
        // console.log("Item Edited.");
        const element = e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
        // set edit item
        
        editElement = element.firstElementChild;
        // set from value
        grocery.value = editElement.innerHTML;
        editFlag = true;
    }
```